# Mysql connect to remote server successfully using command line but access denied when start service

Tags: mysql

I have an internal server, which run MySQL server on port 3306. I connect to this server via VPN

connect successfully using command line. *`10.10.x.x` is my internal server ip*

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql -u adnet -p -h 10.10.x.x
Enter password:
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 4597054
Server version: 5.5.44-37.3 Percona Server (GPL), Release 37.3, Revision 729fbe2
```

But when I start a Java service, I get an error. *`10.79.x.x` is my ip*

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'adnet'@'10.79.x.x' (using password: YES)
```

This is my db config

```
db {
  default {
    url = "jdbc:p6spy:mysql://10.10.x.x:3306/adnet_dev?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    username = "adnet"
    password = "xxx"
  }
}
```

Access denied also happen when I use **Database tool** in **Intellij**

Does anyone have any idea what is the cause of the problem. Thank you

My IP already granted full privileges
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should just grant access to the database from that IPs.

Comment: @Dmitry I update my question

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out, My Ip was granted privilege without `IDENTIFIED BY`. I start my service successfully with password empty

```
db {
  default {
    url = "jdbc:p6spy:mysql://10.10.x.x:3306/adnet_dev?characterEncoding=UTF-8"
    username = "adnet"
    password = ""
  }
}
```